# Jquery auto scroll down when sorting

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I do the sorting feature in HTML5. When I drag the item, my mouse will keep scroll down. I try to put the solution provide by jQuery also cannot work.

Below is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

    var scroll = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "scroll" );
    $( ".selector" ).draggable({ scroll: false });
    $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "scroll", false );
});
```

Anyone can help me to see which part I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. When does it scroll exactly ? What's your html code ?

Comment: <div id="sortable">
    <div  class="card">
        <div class="section-title">Today is <?php echo date('l, M d, Y'); ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="section-title">Announcements</div>
    </div>
</div>

This is my Html, when I dragging the card, my mouse will keep auto scroll down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work

$( "#sortable" ).sortable("option", "scroll", false);